# How can I get my even/odd decryption fucntion to work with a string with an odd length?

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing a decrytion function in python and it seems to only pass a test for strings with even numbers but not odd.

```
def encrypt(messg: str) -> str:
    evens = '' 
    odds = '' 
    for char_index in range(0, len(messg) -1, 2):
        evens += messg[char_index]
        if char_index +1 < len(messg): 
            odds += messg[char_index + 1]
    encrypted = odds + evens
    if len(messg) % 2 != 0:
        encrypted += messg[-1] 
    return encrypted 

def decryption(messg: str) -> str:
    messg_len = len(messg)
    middle = math.ceil(messg_len // 2)
    decrypted = ''
    for i in range(middle):
        if middle + i < messg_len:
            decrypted += messg[middle + i] + messg[i]
    return decrypted
```

I was able to get my encryption fucntion to pass both even and odd strings, but am still struggling with the decryption.

Any help would be appriciated, thank you!

Comment: You haven't shown the encryption method, so we have no way to know why the decryption fails.

Comment: The `//` division operator returns an integer.  Why are you using `math.ceil()` on a number that is already guaranteed to be an integer?

Comment: I just updated with the encryption function, sry I forgot to add!

Comment: The encryption function checks for the input being an odd length, and performs an extra step. You need something analogous in decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decryption` needs to copy the last character as an extra step when the length is odd, just like you do in `encrypt`.

```
def decryption(messg: str) -> str:
    messg_len = len(messg)
    middle = messg_len // 2
    decrypted = ''
    for i in range(middle):
        if middle + i < messg_len:
            decrypted += messg[middle + i] + messg[i]
    if len(messg) % 2 == 1:
        decrypted += messg[-1]
    return decrypted
```